# Unity AddExplosionForce synchronize over the Network Manager

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

im working on a little 3D-Game for 2 player in Unity. The game concept is a space-race, where you have to fly through rings. As an additionally feature i want to give the player the ability to push the other player. So when they hit a specific button their spaceship should send a "shockwave" that hit the other player and pushes him a little back. I wanted to realize this with the Physics.OverlapSphere and AddExplosionForce functions.
I tested this in a local extra scene without the network function and it worked very well.

As i wanted to import the function into the real game, i have the problem that the effect just hit the local player and not the other one. The other one is just lagging weirdly and didn't change his position (In the other game instance also not. It's like the client didn't get the change).

I have to say, I'm already using the Network Manager and the normal movement with "wasd" is working for both players.

Following the code I'm using (It's just the standard example):

```
Vector3 explosionPos = transform.position;
Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(explosionPos, radius);
foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
{
   Rigidbody rb = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

   if (rb != null)
   rb.AddExplosionForce(power, explosionPos, radius, 3.0F);
}
```

Does somebody know, if there is something I have to add for the network thing?

Comment: I have a feeling that the effect you're trying to achieve is going to be very difficult without a serever-authority calculating the physics.  Because of the network latency, player 1 (activating the ability) will see player 2 in a different place than player 2 sees themselves as being in. So transmitting that explosion across to player 2 is going to result in a different amount of force being applied and the game desyncs and you get rubber-banding. Which client is correct? Is player 2's client always correct for player 2's position? Is player 1 because they used the ability?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a [Command] function that will run [ClientRpc] function with the code you provided. It should look something like this:

```
[Command]
void CmdOnExplosion(float power, Vector3 explosionPos, float radius, float upwardsMod)
{
    RpcExplode(power, explosionPos, radius, upwardsMod);
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcExplode(float power, Vector3 explosionPos, float radius, float upwardsMod)
{
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(explosionPos, radius);

    foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
    {
        Rigidbody rb = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        if (rb != null)
        {
            rb.AddExplosionForce(power, explosionPos, radius, 3.0F);
        }
    }
}
```